# Get Key from value using jq

Tags: jq

Dear members of support,

I need to get a key by value. Specifically, I need to get the key 2 search by value AWS2. I am trying to use this example [1] without success. Could you help, please?

```
{
  "1": ["AWS1"],
  "2": ["AWS2"],
  "3": ["AWS3"]
}
```

The entire json is this one

```
{
"ARN": "xxxxx",
"Name": "xxxx",
"Description": "xxxx",
"KmsKeyId": "xxxx",
"RotationEnabled": true,
"RotationLambdaARN": "arggg",
"RotationRules": {
    "AutomaticallyAfterDays": 30
},
"LastRotatedDate": "2020-05-27T12:05:56.061000-03:00",
"LastChangedDate": "2020-05-27T13:05:34.807000-03:00",
"LastAccessedDate": "2020-05-26T21:00:00-03:00",
"Tags": [
    {
        "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name",
        "Value": "medusa-monitoring-alerts-role"
    },
    {
        "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id",
        "Value": "xxx"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Team",
        "Value": "xxx xxx"
    },
    {
        "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id",
        "Value": "xxx"
    }
],
"VersionIdsToStages": {
    "1": [
        "AWS1"
    ],
    "2": [
        "AWS2"
    ],
    "3": [
        "AWS3"
    ]
}
}
```

I am trying

```
.VersionIdsToStages|map_values(select(contains(["AWS2"]))) | keys[0]
```

without sucess.

[1] https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/60

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following :

```
map_values(select(contains(["AWS2"]))) | keys
```

`map_values` lets you iterate on the key/value pairs of an object and transform them. Here we use it to remove the key/value pairs with values that do not contain "AWS2". Then we simply use `keys` to retrieve the keys of those pairs from the transformed object.

If you can assume that only a single value will ever match, you can add a `[0]` to the end to retrieve the key only rather than an array containing it.

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/Wq0IH3sXkl).

Comment: sorry I edited my question. The json as showd is part of another bigger. could you help me, please?

Comment: @Juan easy, just add `.VersionIdsToStages | ` before my answer

Comment: I tried .VersionIdsToStages map_values(select(contains(["AWS2"]))) | keys[0] and .VersionIdsToStages | map_values(select(contains(["AWS2"]))) | keys[0] but I get error

Comment: jq: error (at <stdin>: 43): null (null) and array (["AWS2"]) cannot have thier contaiment checked

Comment: @Juan the second one works with your sample : https://jqplay.org/s/GC8NsXdiq_ ; from your error it seems like you might have a "VersionsIdsToStages" object with null values, e.g. `VersionsIdsToStages : { "1" : null, ...`

Comment: If that's the case you can add a predicate to the `select` call so that it immediately discards null values, e.g. `.VersionIdsToStages | map_values(select(arrays | contains(["AWS2"]))) | keys[0]`